# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator

Tags: android-studio, gradle

After updating AndroidStudio to the latest 3.1.x version gradle complained that annoationProcessors has to be declared separately and suggests that I add 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.10.0' to my annoationProcessor config.

I added it which results in the following error in this run task:

```
run tasks
  :app:transformClassesWithDesugarForAppDebug   11s 442ms
```

error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: no such method: org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocator.lambda$getCallerClass$3(String,String,Stream)Optional/invokeStatic

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: method resolution failed
```

I have also tried to disable the annoation check with this instead of adding the line above:

```
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
    }
```

All this results in the same error above.

I have not added this library as a dependency meaning its part of some other library I'm importing but I'm not sure which.

Is there a way to...

1. Fix this problem with some new magic config change which is documented in some hidden document by google somewhere?
2. If that is not an option, disable this dependency so it doesn't annoy my project?
3. How to find which dependency uses this library so I can get rid of or update that dependency instead?

DependencyInsight:

> Configure project :androidlib 
>   publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/debug, src/debug/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/debug, src/nullnullDebug]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
>   Could not find google-services.json while looking in [src/nullnull/release, src/release/nullnull, src/nullnull, src/release, src/nullnullRelease]
>   registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to remove all libraries including `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.10.0` to make it work.

But look through Martin Zeitler's answer as its very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you'd have to add both packages, `log4j-api` & `log4j-core` ...because [it says](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/index.html) that `org.apache.logging.log4j.util` is the `Internal utility classes for the Log4j 2 API`.

```
 dependencies {
     api "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.1"
     implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1"
}
```

one can list all/specific module's dependencies alike this:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies >> ./results/dependencies.txt

./gradlew :app:dependencies --configuration debugCompileClasspath
```

in order to list all the available configurations:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies | grep ' - ' | grep -v '(n)' | grep -v 'deprecated'
```

then one can list the dependencies per individual build configuration:

```
./gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration debugCompileClasspath --dependency log4j-core
```

have not tried that, but have you ever tried something alike ...

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.1"
}
```

here's the [annotationProcessor](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration?utm_source=android-studio#annotationProcessor_config) migration documentation.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I have tried them all now but still haven't been able to get rid of the error.

Comment: @just_user and what does `dependencyInsight` say?

Comment: that `StackLocator` might be wrongfully constructed, https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.html ...there is no `getCallerClass(String,String,Stream)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what i find strange. The project worked before with the same dependencies and then some android studio updates came in between and now this error. I have added the output of the dependencyInsight to the question. Complains about google-services.json, is that related?

Comment: Found this issue which seems to be more or less the same: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2384#issuecomment-376793947